# UITextFields text in custom UITableViewCell appears in other cell while Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am new to iOS development. i create my app in Xcode 6(Storyboard).

My problem is text enter into textfield, scroll the table view that shuffle the textfield text to other text field randomly. There are two question i saw in stack-overflow like this. but that  answer are not solve question.

1. **MoneyEntry.xib**  is a uitableviewcell with one label and one text box. And add class file to it and connect IBOutlet and add identifier to the uitableviewcell as "MoneyEntryIdentifier".

   ```
   //MoneyEntryTableViewCell.h

   @interface MoneyEntryTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

   //Money Entry Cell
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblMemName;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textAmount;

   @end


   //MoneyEntryTableViewCell.m
   #import "MoneyEntryTableViewCell.h"

   @implementation MoneyEntryTableViewCell

   @synthesize lblMemName,textAmount;
   - (void)awakeFromNib {
   }

   - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
   }
   @end
   ```
2. In Main.storyboard add UITableView and connect IBOutlet and add Datasource and delegate.

   ```
   //MoneyDetailViewController.h

   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   @interface MoneyDetailViewController : UIViewController
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblVwMoneyEntry;
   @end


   //MoneyDetailViewController.m
    @interface MoneyDetailViewController ()
    {
      NSArray *tabledata;
    }
    @end

    @implementation MoneyDetailViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     tabledata = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto",@"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee",@"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", nil];
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tabledata count];
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MoneyEntryIdentifier";
    static NSString *CellNib = @"MoneyEntry";
    MoneyEntryTableViewCell *cell = (MoneyEntryTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
     NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
     cell = (MoneyEntryTableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UILabel     *lblname  = (UILabel *)    [cell lblMemName];
    UITextField *txtfield = (UITextField *)[cell textAmount];
    txtfield.tag = indexPath.row;
    lblname.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    txtfield.placeholder =@"0.00";
    cell.selectionStyle =UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
    }

   @end
   ```

Please explain me detail. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer.... Just get the textfield text into Dictionary setObject by label text and again check by label Text assign the text to corresponding Textfield.. here is my code...

```
//In Interface
NSMutableDictionary *amounts;
amounts =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MoneyEntryIdentifier";
static NSString *CellNib = @"MoneyEntry";
MoneyEntryTableViewCell *cell = (MoneyEntryTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (MoneyEntryTableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

UILabel     *lblname  = (UILabel *)    [cell lblMemName];
lblname.tag =100;
UITextField *txtfield = (UITextField *)[cell textAmount];
txtfield.tag =indexPath.row;

[txtfield addTarget:self  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
lblname.text = tabledata[indexPath.row];
txtfield.placeholder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];


if ([amounts valueForKey:lblname.text] != nil) {
    txtfield.text = [amounts valueForKey:lblname.text];
} else {
    txtfield.text = @"";
}

cell.selectionStyle =UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
}

 -(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)txtField
{
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[txtField.superview viewWithTag:100];
NSString *labelString = label.text;
NSString *textFieldString = txtField.text;
[amounts setObject:textFieldString forKey:labelString];
}
```

There is no error while scroll table view...

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something to store the text entered into the textfield. The `UITableView` works by reusing `UITableViewCells` that are not visible or gone out of the screen to save memory.

So if you enter some text into a textfield in the cell and the cell goes out of the screen, the cell gets queued up for later use. As you scroll new rows are added from this queue, which bring the `textfield` with your previous text back. This is why you see your text randomly popping everywhere.

You need to save the data from each `textfield` in a separate array and reset it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Your code..
    Item *item = itemArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.txtfield.text = item.amount
}
```

You can use the `UITextField's` `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event to store the changed array values.

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)txtField
{
    Item *item = itemArray[txtField.tag] 
    item.amount = txtField.text
}
```

You add the textField change method like this

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Use a custom class called Item to store your data.

```
class Item
{
     @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *itemName;
     @property (nonatomic) float amount;  
}
```

`itemArray` will contain your items.

```
Item *it1 = [[Item alloc]init]
it1.itemName = @"Eggs Benedict"
it1.amount = ""
.... 
itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:it1,it2,it3,nil];
```

Comment: it doesn't work. textfield does not call textFieldDidChange method.But i add delegate to textfield.

Comment: the textFieldDidChange is not in the delegate. Please check my modified answer

Comment: Yes.That add text into amount(Mutable-array). When Scroll it return correct text to edited textfield. but Unedited textfield are also has that text. This is the code `if([amounts count] > 0 && [amounts count] > indexPath.row){ txtfield.text=[amounts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; }`

Comment: mutable array isn't enough. I recommend making a class Item which has your item names like Egg Benedict and amount in it. will show in my answer.

Comment: Can you Please explain me detail how to use it. i didn't use classes in objective-c before

Comment: please check my answer on how to use it.